# JS no longer working after WordPress update - Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-waypoints

I updated a website I am working on to the latest WordPress last week. None of the custom JS is working anymore and I can't work out why.

Even if I remove it in sections to try and isolate the issue, I always get 'Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function'.

I cannot work out what has caused this to happen.

As far as I can see, all the scripts load as expected.

Unfortunately all the JS in my custom file has been acquired either from Stack Overflow or other online resources - I did not write it myself (only amended) and thus am struggling to diagnose the issue.

Any help would be appreciated

```
// apply effect to pages

var $headereffect = $('.hero-effect');

$headereffect.waypoint(function (direction) {
   if (direction == 'down') {
   $headereffect.addClass('hero-effect-animation');
   } else {
   $headereffect.removeClass('hero-effect-animation');
   }

}, { offset:'1px' });



// apply effect to default page headers



var $headereffect = $('#page-header');

$headereffect.waypoint(function (direction) {
   if (direction == 'down') {
   $headereffect.addClass('hero-effect');
   } else {
   $headereffect.removeClass('hero-effect');
   }

}, { offset:'1px' });
```

Comment: You must include [jquery](https://digwp.com/2009/06/including-jquery-in-wordpress-the-right-way/) at the top of your page

Comment: You need to use `jQuery` instead of `$` in your custom.js file. At some places you are already using `jQuery`

Comment: Not sure why the downvote - It would be nice to have an explanation so I know for next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My wild guess is to use *jQuery* instead of the *$* as sometimes the latter is used by other scripting libraries and this causes issues and conflicts.

So

```
var $headereffect = $('.hero-effect');
```

becomes

```
var $headereffect = jQuery('.hero-effect');
```

This will fix the current issue but others also may be raised on a later stage. Inspect your code and make sure you use a consistent jQuery reference.

Options to handle the **$ issue** the jQuery way can be found [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/). From a practical point of view, you can put jQuery into "no conflict" mode by using shortcut for jQuery. In this case "$j" instead of the default "$":

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
$j(function(){
    $j("#sidebar li a").hover(function(){
        $j(this).stop().animate({
            paddingLeft: "20px&"
        }, 400);
    }, function() {
        $j(this).stop().animate({
            paddingLeft: 0
        }, 400);
    });
});
```

A **best practice** as [Wordpress suggest](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/javascript-best-practices/#jquery) is to wrap your code in immediately invoked function expression, pass jQuery to it and use the $ internally like this:

```
( function( $ ) {
    // Your code goes here
} )( jQuery );
```

Comment: When I change the first two waypoints to this I then get:

`Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
    at t.handler [as callback] (custom.js?ver=5.3:54)
    at t.trigger (custom.js?ver=5.3:8)
    at i.flushTriggers (custom.js?ver=5.3:8)
    at custom.js?ver=5.3:8`

I dont understand why this was working perfectly 2 weeks ago

Comment: Hm.. I can't see the issue on the website, is it working now?

Comment: Hi Goran - So I have just gone through and switched all the $ to jQuery and it seems to be working - But, do you think this might break again in the future? Obviously I don't want to hand it off and then it break - do you think no-conflict mode is better?

Comment: Yes, it's a better approach. Thus you make sure that other libraries using the $ as a reference won't conflict with your custom code.

Comment: Also - do you perhaps know what might have caused the previous way to suddenly not work?

Comment: I can only guess what caused it but it could be:
a) custom code copied and applied directly
b) third party plugins changing what $ reference to
c) WP core specifics but the chance is near 0% :)

Comment: I've had a quick look at that resource you supplied (I will look more thoroughly later) - but what confuses me is that I haven't added any jQuery as I could see the theme was already loading it. When I inspect the page, it loads these two scripts:
`jquery.js?ver=1.12.4-wp` 
and
`jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1`

If no conflict is used for multiple versions of JQuery - and I'm not calling more than the above, I don't understand why you would use this (assuming I am correct that the two files above are different).

Comment: The latter (query-migrate.min.js?ver=1.4.1) is not a different version of jQuery, it's just a helper library that preserves the compatibility for jQuery code written for older versions of jQuery. As jQuery evolves some of the methods may be deprecated in the newer version so the migrate script "saves" you.

Comment: Yes so this is what I understood it to be - but therefore isn't it safe to say that the site only calls 1 version of JQuery and therefore noConflict mode is not required? Apologies if I am not uderstanding this correctly.

Comment: No worries :) The noConflict mode does not deal with different versions of jQuery but with entirely different javascript libraries, similar to not so similar to jQuery. [Here's more on this topic](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/avoid-conflicts-other-libraries/). Basically other plugins, the theme itself or a custom code may use the $ as a reference, it's a common practice, so you are better off using jQuery in no conflict mode.

Comment: Ah right, that makes more sense. So for example I have custom Twitter Feed plugin that uses a custom JS file. So this may be an example of when you may need to us no conflict mode correct? I'm trying to understand as thoroughly as possible so I don't end up back on here on my next update!

Comment: We can only speculate which plugin may break the code but in order to be safe, use the no conflict approach or wrap your code in IIFE as Wordpress suggests. Either way will keep you safe and won't need to worry about conflicts with other plugins :)

Comment: Okay that's great thanks - I just used the Twitter feed as a random example. Thanks so much for taking the time to explain all this, I really appreciate it :)